# How to configure Magento 2 Theme/Design via the Command-Line?

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, cli, linux

I'm doing some server configuration related tasks and was looking for a way to configure the theme of a store/website via the command-line.

I'm setting up a store with a custom theme (e.g. "`Vendor/code`") and I would like to activate it without entering the *adminhtml* website but set the theme on the command-line / in the shell / bash script.

Comment: Created custom theme, you want to set for store ?

Comment: @SHPatel: Yes, created a custom theme and then doing semi/automated deployments.  Edited the question to reflect this better and have a bit more context.

Answer (score 5):

This does not accomplish OP's goal of utilizing the Magento CLI, however it does work for usage in automation which is what OP (and myself) was looking to achieve.

## Edit: 2022.08.02

A "Magento way" to programmatically revise the theme is to utilize dependency injection to revise the value of the `frontend` key of the `$themes` array passed to the constructor of the `\Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design` object. This array serves to configure what the default theme will be for an area, if one is not already configured (refer to the logic in `getConfigurationDesignTheme()` of this same class).

This approach therefore works well in deployment pipelines, if we desire to have the theme set upon initial `setup:install` and we do not yet know the `theme.theme_id` database value that will belong to our theme.

Example `etc/di.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Foo/bar</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Because we are seeking to override existing XML configuration of `Magento_Theme`, be sure that the module also specifies a `<sequence>` node in its `etc/module.xml` file to assure the custom module is loaded afterwards and its value takes precedence.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Foo_Bar">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

If you have a multi-store installation with various themes per store, this approach would not be suitable as it serves to only set the fallback theme when none is set.

In a multi-store situation, a "Magento way" to accomplish theme configuration via the code would be to register a `Setup/RecurringData.php` script. This script would have to perform something along the lines of instantiating a Theme Collection object, filtering by the `code` your theme would result in, retrieving the `theme_id`, then saving the `design/theme/theme_id` value for the appropriate scope.

Despite probably only needing to do this once, it is unfortunate that we cannot merely create a Data Patch to reliably configure this upon first `setup:install` of a project. The reason being, is that it is `Magento\Theme\Setup\RecurringData` that registers into the `theme` table the existence of themes. Because RecurringData scripts run after Data Patches, a record for our theme would not yet exist in the `theme` table at the time that our Data Patch runs. Therefore we must resort to a RecurringData script instead.

---

## Original Answer:

If your automation has access to the database, we can set the theme by querying the appropriate tables and performing INSERT statements.

### Set Theme at a global scope:

```sql
INSERT INTO core_config_data
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'default', 0, 'design/theme/theme_id', (SELECT theme_id FROM theme WHERE code = 'VendorName/ThemeNameOne'))
```

### Set Theme at a Website scope:

```sql
INSERT INTO core_config_data
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'websites', (SELECT website_id FROM store_website WHERE code = 'website_code_one'), 'design/theme/theme_id', (SELECT theme_id FROM theme WHERE code = 'VendorName/ThemeNameOne')),
  (NULL, 'websites', (SELECT website_id FROM store_website WHERE code = 'website_code_two'), 'design/theme/theme_id', (SELECT theme_id FROM theme WHERE code = 'VendorName/ThemeNameTwo'))
;
```

### Set Theme at a Store scope:

```sql
INSERT INTO core_config_data
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'stores', (SELECT store_id FROM store WHERE code = 'store_code_one'), 'design/theme/theme_id', (SELECT theme_id FROM theme WHERE code = 'VendorName/ThemeNameOne')),
  (NULL, 'stores', (SELECT store_id FROM store WHERE code = 'store_code_two'), 'design/theme/theme_id', (SELECT theme_id FROM theme WHERE code = 'VendorName/ThemeNameTwo'))
;
```

Variable strings above to replace:

- `website_code_one`
- `website_code_two`
- `store_code_one`
- `store_code_two`
- `VendorName/ThemeNameOne`
- `VendorName/ThemeNameTwo`

If you have more or less themes to set in your automation process, we can see above how we'll simply need to add/remove VALUE sets to the INSERT query.

### Final Note:

The queries above are under the assumption that there are no records in `core_config_data` for your themes. This will be the case if your automated process is performing a fresh installation of Magento, or performing a fresh install + Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration. If this is not the case for you and you have records with matching `scope,scope_id,path` values, you'll need to revise your strategy to either perform a `DELETE` query prior to, revise the queries to be an `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to find a direct Magento CLI command so far, I could work around with a Bash and Magerun:

```
$ THEME_ID="$(n98-magerun2.phar dev:theme:list --format=csv \
  | grep 'Vendor/code' | cut -d, -f1)" \
  ; test -n "${THEME_ID}" \
  && n98-magerun2.phar config:set design/theme/theme_id "${THEME_ID}"
```

This sequence sets the configuration path for the theme_id to the one of the named theme (by it's code, which is **"`Vendor/code`"** in the example).

In case the operation fails, this has a non-zero status.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is still rather hard to do, I created a simple module to allow for enabling a theme from the CLI anyway: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_ThemeCommands Example command would be `bin/magento theme:change Hyva/default 1 stores`.

Answer (score -1):

The only command related to themes out of the box in Magento 2 is `php bin/magento theme:uninstall` which can be used to uninstall a theme.

I suggest you create your own command following [the example in the sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-command) so you can develop your custom code to configure themes properly.

Also I suggest you read the official documentation to create your own command: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html

Comment: I would consider creating a CLI command off-topic in the light of an answer (yes it's possible, and programming it yourself is always the solution of everything, and so its kinda superfluous for an answer here) - and consider that more a comment. But thanks for your efforts and your commentary.