# Magento 2: Setting theme ID is not working by using config:set

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.2.5, cli

I found xpath `design/theme/theme_id` in `vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignInterface.php:28`.

I'm trying to set new ID and there is an error:

```
magento config:set design/theme/theme_id 7
The "design/theme/theme_id" path does not exist
```

What's wrong with it? Is there described reason why it doesn't work?

Other configuration paths work fine.

Magento `v2.2.5`.

In this case related question-answer doesn't work: [How to configure Mangento 2 Theme/Design via the Command-Line?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142315/how-to-configure-mangento-2-theme-design-via-the-command-line/142318) (It doesn't work neither by using `bin/magento` nor `n98-magerun2`).

Comment: All paths are declared in module's system.xml